# How to include local as highlight group?

Tags: vimrc, neovim

I thought thats super duper easy to customize within semshi. But it seems it aint. Or at least i dont find the correct file, command or what so ever to archieve this.
To put it simply i just want to have the hightlight of the highlight group local included.
By default its excluded. Which in a sense i understand but i want it included. Im very new to vim/neovim and what so ever.

I tried to set Local Highlighting in my vimrc

```
function MyCustomHighlights()
    hi semshiGlobal      ctermfg=red guifg=#ff0000
endfunction
autocmd FileType python call MyCustomHighlights()
```

also with

```
autocmd ColorScheme * call MyCustomHighlights()
```

I also tried to remove the local hl group of the cluded hl groups list

```
let g:semshi#excluded_hl_groups=[]
```

But it doesnt work. Im out of ideas and i dont find another solution.

I fine with the semshi color for local variables i just want them to be included in the highlighting.

@edit to be more clear:
I expect/want:
Local Variables to be symantic highlighted with the color which is definied by semshi itself.

Whats happening:
Local variables are not highlighted because by default  semshi excludes local variables/identifier  for performance. But im a machine learnign engineer we dont have huge files so shouldnt be a problem.

I just want to have local

```
g:semshi#excluded_hl_groups ['local']
```

to be returning no groups. I dont find any solution in the documentation of semshi

Comment: Welcome to vi.stackexchange! Since you're new to Vim (and since I don't know how to answer your question) I want to make sure you know about the extensive built in help system.  Have you done `:help highlight`, `:help syntax`. and `:help autocommand`? These might help you find what you're looking for.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I'm not exactly sure I understand your question. It seems like you refer to a plugin: can you be specific about which? Can you also explain what you want to happen more clearly, and what is currently happening that is not correct? Please [edit] to include more detail.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble oh yeah sorry forgot about that its semshi im using for symantic highlighting

Comment: @Tollpatsch Please [edit] in links; we don't know what semshi is without guessing.

Comment: And please do _not_ put answers ("Solution was to: `let g:semshi#excluded_hl_groups=[]` in the correct vimrc. Showhow i didnt had mine linked.") in questions: post them as answers.